# gvim + vim-latex: behaviour of abbreviations with shift+enter

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

1. **The following happens with gvim, not vim**
2. **I have the vim-latex plugin installed, and this only happens on .tex files**

Playing with abbreviation in insert mode i noticed the following unexpected (to me) behaviour.
Defining an abbreviation such as

```
:iab m <m>
```

or any similar "container" abbreviation such as

```
:iab m \(m\)
:iab m \m\
:iab m [m]
```

and so on, i get the expected behaviour when simply typing in insert mode

```
m<space>
```

However, if I type

```
m<shift><enter>
```

or

```
m<ctrl><enter>
```

the "container characters" are doubled, for example in the first two cases above I get

```
<<m>>
\(\(m\)\)
```

I don't find this kind of behaviour in the abbreviations section of the man page, nor in the relative vim.wikia page.

My OS is Arch Linux, the vim version if 7.4.

Why does this happen? Can I prevent it? How?

---

### EDIT:

I also submitted the problem on the [vim-latex mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vim-latex/).
[Here](http://sourceforge.net/p/vim-latex/mailman/vim-latex-devel/thread/542A8FBE.4000206@mathematik.tu-chemnitz.de/) is the response I got:

> Hi,
>
> this seems to be a strange interaction with the IMAP-features of the
>   latex-suite.
>
> I tried
>
> :iab a (m)
>   :iab m [a]
>
> Now, a  =>  (m) a => ([a])
>
> Here, first a is expanded to (m) and the inner m is expanded to [a].
>
> If one uses
>
> let Imap_FreezeImap=1
>
> triggers no expansions, but  works correctly.
>
> I have no clue how to fix this.
>
> Best regards, Gerd

Comment: It does no such thing on my system. Can you a) post your OS and `vim --version`, and try if it does it with `vim -u NONE`?

Comment: It is not reproducable in macvim 7.3. Please provide the vim version

Comment: @Amadan added more info. If not enough to reproduce I will post the output of `vim --version`

Comment: "I have the vim-latex plugin installed, and this only happens on .tex files". There we go. You might want to contact [vim-latex people](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=contact&title=Contact). (Sorry, I don't use vim-latex, so I have no idea about your issue.)

Comment: @Amadan well, I will if it turns out to actually be a bug. It could very well be a feature, I just don't find it documented on the appropriate documentations (which can be my fault).

Comment: It's not a bug-only mailing list. What it is is the place that you are most likely to get questions on vim-latex answered. That said, I tried to install vim-latex, and couldn't reproduce on MacVim 7.4.

Comment: cross-posted on vi.stackexchange: http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2245/602